# How to find Twins in same table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table with:

```
columnid, firstname, lastname, dob, motherid
```

Now I have to find a twins in this table with same `dob` and same `motherid`. How can I make a query for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) in conjunction with [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) and [HAVING](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) -- The easiest solution to this is a simple query (non-nested SELECT)

```
SELECT     firstname,
           lastname,
           COUNT(*)
FROM       mysql_table
GROUP BY   dob,
           motherid
HAVING     COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: This can at most find one twin in each pair of twins.

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple births, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.motherid = t.motherid and
                    t2.dob >= t.dob - interval 1 day and
                    t2.dob <= t.dob + interval 1 day
             );
```

Because going into labor doesn't adhere to calendar conventions, multiple births can happen over the span of midnight.